# Visual Basic Background Image Flicker on PRESSING TAB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

I am making an application using VB.NET 2010 and I have set a background image which flickers every time I open any new Form or hit tab for jumping from textbox to textbox

By pressing (tab) it only flickers once but always flicker when ever I close the form and open again.
I have tried everything; background image set to, `STRETCHED`, `CENTRE`, `ZOOM` but still it's the same.

Only thing is when I remove my background all is well, can you help me; what could be the reason of this?

Screenshot is attached please have look

[image]

Comment: Nobody can diagnose a flicker issue from looking at a screenshot.  Post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: There is actually no specific code, There are two forms 1 is Main From as MDI and how do i open another form is, when we click from top menu the code goes like this to shwo from ... form2.mdiparent = me .... form2.show

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the form's DoubleBuffered property to True.  However, by looking at your screenshot, it seems like you'd be better off just using a PictureBox control to contain the image.

Comment: How can i use picture box as maximize screen size ?

Comment: I have already tried DoubleBuffered property to True and false both but still no idea, i would like to know if there is any better way to use background image ? which does not have such issues ?